# How to print in pdf with RMarkdown the indentations of the text

Tags: r, text, r-markdown

I am trying to report in a pdf file the following text

````
---
title: "Example"
author: "X"
date: "todayàs date"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Title

1) somthing: 

 ● somethingelse xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
````

However, by running it, it does not return the same indentations. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at unordered lists in https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf?